# Find out whether Facebook page is live streaming

Tags: facebook

Is possible to find out whether some facebook page is live streaming right now? I was looking at Facebook API and from there it seems to me that it is not possible since `/{page_id}/live_videos` seems to be working only if you are an admin of the page (or you have been granted the access) since you cannot read live videos of public without page access token.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can. This is actually called a WebHook (simultaneous notification of a certain app/user about changes made on the page). To do this you will have to create a Facebook App that will be subscribed to the changes made on a certain page that you want to track.

You can simply do this from the dashboard of the app or through `Graph API 2.7`(since this version supports `live_videos`) calling `{app-id}/subscriptions` and choose any of Page Object Subscriptions, which are available through Facebook API(in your case `live_videos`).

For this kind of subscriptions your app needs to be whitelisted in order not to spam or re-transmit the information received from a certain page.

To get more information about WebHook implementation please read Facebook API documenation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks

Comment: Isn't here still the same problem, that is that you actually have to be the admin of the page you want to know about whether is live streaming or not? I am asking this because at Facebook documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/app/subscriptions#publish) for subscribing to specific webhook is written this `Subscriptions for the object type page will only be valid for Pages that have installed the app. You can install the app for a Page using the /{page-id}/subscribed_apps edge.`.

Comment: No, subscription is actually done in the way like regular user presses 'follow' button on the page and keeps getting updates. However, as I told, your app will have to pass a whitelisting test to stay subscribed. Once whitelisted, you will not need that certain page to install your app.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on whitelisting - where and how can your app get whitelisted? Is there even some higher chance for unknown, brand new, non-spam app to get whitelisted?

Comment: You will firstly have to create the application and submit it for a review through app dashboard to Facebook team. While submitting, you will have to explain in details for which purposes you are requesting permission for a certain data. If you ensure them that you are not going to waive against their policy and this info will make your app complete, they will let you subscribe for those updates that you are asking for.

Comment: It seems that I can't test out Webhooks without it actually requiring some setup on my server first (the Callback URL). How do you test this out locally?

Comment: You cannot DIRECTLY get webhooks on localhost, because facebook calls your webhook URL with SSL. However, you can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to tunnel your localhost address, which will allow you to receive them.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is quite late already but for those that may stumble on it like I did, Yes it's possible.
As clearly stated in the documentation
[Page Live Videos - Facebook API Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/live_videos/)

You will need to make a `GET` Request to the endpoint below with the appropriate parameters:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/{page-id}/live_videos
```

Where page_id is the Facebook Page ID you with to check for active Live Stream

The endpoint also expect `broadcast_status` whose value for your use case would be `LIVE`

**Note: You will need and app setup on Facebook for developers platform and your query would have to be via the app**
Further details can be found in the documentation whose link I provided at the initial part of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get a returned string if there is any, from:

GET /v2.7/{page-id}/live_videos HTTP/1.1

Host: graph.facebook.com

You can read more in: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/live_videos/

Comment: Don't you have to actually be the owner of the page? Since you need a page access token? So far I get `(#100) No permission to perform current operation.` when I am trying this call.