# Get permalink when a Facebook page starts a live stream?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to automate getting notified of a Facebook live stream by a public page, and also it's permalink.

Based on answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39237926/find-out-whether-facebook-page-is-live-streaming) question, I would need to submit an App Review to Facebook to access the required permission to use Facebook's API in order to get the permalink to the live stream.

Because I'm writing this app just for my own use, I'm trying to avoid all the complicated steps to submit for an App Review. Is there any other way to get notified when a Facebook page starts a live stream and get the permalink to the live stream other than for example, scraping the Facebook page with `selenium`?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible via Facebook API's because `/{page_id}/live_videos` is only accessible if you are an admin of the page or have been granted access per the linked post.